# Unordered List Element shows Bullets when it shouldnt

Tags: html, css, dotnetnuke

I have a HTML unordered list element that should have no bullet points shown(I am using my own images for bullet points).

**My Problem:** The default black bullet points are appearing on the UL when there shouldn't be any.
[image]

The [website](http://exds-test.epicservices.com.au/Training.aspx) is a Dot Net Nuke run website and it looks like the Skin CSS is causing this error. Do you know how I can stop the back bullets from appearing?

My CSS:

```
.infoTab ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside; 
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.infoTab li {
    background-image: url("../../Site Images/headingIcon.png");
    background-position: 0px 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `skin.css` line 281 you have

```
ul li {
    list-style-position: outside;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

then default.css line 104

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

, which overrides

```
.infoTab ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, although I've removed the list style type attribute from skin.css and it still shows the bullets? Any ideas what else is causing it?